# MPMoviePlayerController % of data bufferd

Tags: iphone

While using `MPMoviePlayerController` is there any way to find how much Percentage of data finished while buffering the video?

My aim is to show the progress bar that showing how much percentage is loaded and show its numeric count of percentage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked out the Apple documentation for the `MPMoviePlayerController` ?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Here you can find two properties that might help you. `duration` and `playableDuration`, it's not an exact fit, but pretty close. One thing you will need to implement yourself is a way to intelligently query these properties, for example maybe you might want to use an `NSTimer` and fetch the info from your `MPMovePlayerController` instance every 0.5 seconds.

For example assume you have a property called `myPlayer` of type `MPMoviePlayerController`, you will initiate it in your init method of the view controller etc...

Then followed by this:

```
self.checkStatusTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5 
                                                target:self 
                                              selector:@selector(updateProgressUI) 
                                              userInfo:nil 
                                               repeats:YES];
```

And a method like this to update the UI:

```
- (void)updateProgressUI{
    if(self.myPlayer.duration == self.myPlayer.playableDuration){
        // all done
        [self.checkStatusTimer invalidate];
    }
    int percentage = roundf( (myPlayer.playableDuration / myPlayer.duration)*100 );
    self.progressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%", percentage];
}
```

Note the double percentage sign in our `-stringWithFormat`, this is another format specifier to resolve to a `%` sign. For more on Format specifiers [see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Comment: Could you please give me any example codes? I am illiterate with this stuff. I hope u don't bother.

Comment: Hai daniel, i saw your reply and i think it work fine. unfortunately i am using a class file that making some issues now to try this code. Anyway thanks for your effort and kindness.